# build vim8 and python3

Tags: python-3.x, vim, pyenv

environment: centos

My global python version is 2.7, but I use pyenv to create a python version 3.6.
I want to build vim8 with python3.
According the instruction on the net, I use

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
        --enable-multibyte \
        --enable-python3interp=yes \
        --with-python3-config-dir=/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3 \
        --enable-gui=gtk2 \
        --enable-cscope \
        --prefix=/usr/local
make && make install
```

Vim8 is built ok, but it without python3:

```
vim --version
```

The list shows -python and -python3.

I dont't know what's wrong.

Comment: I think you need `python3-dev` package and I'm sure you need to point to `config` directory: `--with-python3-config-dir=/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/config` or `--with-python3-config-dir=/root/.local/lib/python3.6/config` or something like that.

Comment: I follow the instruction, but still fail.